# I can't add coordinates attributes in Power View

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, sharepoint-2013, powerview

Currently I'm trying to add my coordinates attributes to the latitude and longitude field of power view but power view doesn't let me add the attributes to the fields. Both attribute data type in the dimension is double. The data comes from a multidimensional cube and power view is integrated with SharePoint 2013. I can't use the location field since it gives wrong location based in the names of the cities and countries. How can i make this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution for this problem but it seems to align with the multidimensional model limitation with power view. Here is a link explaining ["Power View for Multidimensional Model"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198310.aspx).

Update: I managed to solve the above question by creating a data model using power pivot that contained all the attributes that i was going to use for the power view report. In the data model i change the latitude and longitude to be decimal and chose to be recognized as latitude and longitude. This Excel sheet was uploaded to the PowerPivot gallery in SharePoint. Then I created a PowerView Report from the Excel file and finally I was able to create the map correctly.